# Does the series $\sum_{1 \leq i < j} \frac{e^{- (j-i)}}{ij}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I recently came across this series.
$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \sum_{1 \leq i < j\leq t} \frac{1}{i}\frac{1}{j}\exp(- (j-i)).$$
(Note the strict inequality $i<j$).

Computer simulations seem to suggest that this converges, however I am unable to show whether this happens. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all terms of the double summation are nonnegative we can change the order of summation without altering convergence. Then

\begin{align}
\sum^\infty_{i=1}\sum^\infty_{j=i+1}\frac{e^{-(j-i)}}{ij}&=\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}\sum^\infty_{j=i+1}\frac{e^{-(j-i)}}{j}=\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac{1}{i}\sum^\infty_{j=1}\frac{e^{-j}}{j+i}\\
&=\sum^\infty_{j=1}e^{-j}\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac{1}{(i+j)i}\leq
\sum^\infty_{j=1}e^{-j}\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac{1}{i^2}=\frac{e^{-1}}{1-e^{-1}}\sum^\infty_{i=1}\frac{1}{i^2}<\infty
\end{align}

Answer (score 4):

The sum increases when $t$ increases, so we only need an upper bound to prove the convergence.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{1 \leq i < j\leq t} \frac{1}{i}\frac{1}{j}\exp(-(j-i))
&=& \sum_{1 \leq i \le t-1}\sum_{i+1 \leq j \le t}\frac{1}{ij}\exp(-(j-i))\\
&=& \sum_{1 \leq i \le t-1}\sum_{1 \leq k \le t-i}\frac{1}{i(i+k)}\exp(-k)\\
&\le& \sum_{1 \leq i \le t-1}\sum_{1 \leq k \le t-1}\frac{1}{i(i+1)}\exp(-k)\\
&=& \sum_{1 \leq i \le t-1}\Big(\frac{1}{i}-\frac{1}{i(i+1)}\Big) \times \sum_{1 \leq k \le t-1}\exp(-k)\\
&=& \Big(1-\frac{1}{t}\Big) \times \frac{e^{-1}-e^{-k}}{1-e^{-1}}\\
&\le&\frac{e^{-1}}{1-e^{-1}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Should the index of the exponential be $i$ instead of $k$ in the second line

Comment: I really don't understand what's going on in the second line

Comment: I get the first line (the first equation) it's the second equals that's throwing me off.

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake. I have modified the way to get an upper bound.